# Minimizing a function over a Domain

Tags: python, function, optimization, minimize

I have a function f(x) which is defined over a domain x = [0, 1]. 
When I try to minimize the function using scipy.optimize.fmin, apparently, the x exceeds the domain and I get an error.(it is because of the operations that scipy.optimize.fmin does on the function)

Is there a way to minimize the function in a way that I clarify that the input values should be bound to a domain?

Answer (score 0):

See in SciPy docs: [Constrained minimization of multivariate scalar functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#constrained-minimization-of-multivariate-scalar-functions-minimize)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the analytical version of the function. So I won't be able to find the Jacobian.
"fminbound" from "scipy.optimize" maybe useful. Do you know how can I pass the domains for a function of two variables to this method ?